# git describe --match returns wrong tag name if commit has two tags

Tags: git, git-tag, git-describe

I'm trying to add an extra tag for the commit to be able later to select this commit by `git describe` with `--match` pattern;

When I use `--match` to catch usual commits with one tag everything works fine.

But when I try to --match commit with two tags by pattern "deployed", I get very weird tag like, for example:

I have commit: `b946bdf (tag: a@0.0.1) Publish`

I add "deployed" tag: `b946bdf (tag: a@0.0.1, tag: deployed) Publish`

Then I run `git describe --abbrev=0 --match "deployed"`

And the result of this command is `a@0.0.1-9-g1e5c94cc55fded72114b801bd47d8d29e7721255`

If I try to use `--abbrev=1` I get `a@0.0.1-9-g1e5c9`

And the most interesting that the `-9-g1e5c94cc55fded72114b801bd47d8d29e7721255` is not even a has of this commit. I have no idea why and where from I get this weird identifier.

I want to get a clean tag like `a@0.0.1`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what's your git version ? can you update to the latest "2.32" version ?

Answer (score 0):

The `--match` option to `git describe` takes a shell-style glob pattern, such as `a*z`.  It then runs the tags listed by `git tags` through a shell-style matcher.<sup>1</sup>  Hence, given the glob pattern `a*z`, tags named `abuzz` and `aveloz` would match, but a tag named `arbiter` or `fuzz` would not.

Your glob pattern is `deployed`, and since there are no wildcard characters allowed, the only *allowed* tag by this `--match` option is `deployed` itself.  You *do* have a tag named `deployed`, and you gave only one `--match`, so this is the only one allowed.

If I create such a tag, I can use it:

```
$ git tag -a deployed -m silly
$ git describe --abbrev=0 --match deployed
deployed
```

This tag can't be used for any earlier revision, of course:

```
$ git describe --abbrev=0 --match deployed HEAD~
fatal: No tags can describe '98f3f03bcbf4e0eda498f0a0c01d9bd90de9e106'.
Try --always, or create some tags.
```

Deleting the tag produces an appropriate error:

```
$ git tag -d deployed
Deleted tag 'deployed' (was a464a376ca)
$ git describe --abbrev=0 --match deployed 
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
```

I cannot explain your output.  There have been bugs in `git describe`; [the release notes for Git 2.15.0 point one out](https://github.com/git/git/blob/75ae10bc75336db031ee58d13c5037b929235912/Documentation/RelNotes/2.15.0.txt#L403-L405), for instance.  But this would not produce the output you show (I think).  What version of Git are you using?

---

<sup>1</sup>This is actually all built in to `git describe` itself, which doesn't have to run `git tags`.  The effect is the same, though.  Note that shell glob patterns may need quoting to protect them from the shell, depending on your shell.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to get the hash of the commit tagged by `deployed`, just use `git rev-parse` :

```
# works for any type of tag :
git rev-parse deployed^{}

# works if 'deployed' is a plain tag :
git rev-parse deployed
```

If `deployed` is an annotated tag, `git rev-parse deployed` (without the `^{}`) will give you *the hash of the tag object itself*, not the hash of the commit that is tagged.

---

this doesn't explain the weird output you get from `git describe`, but I thought it was worth mentioning this command.